How can I use back button in angular project dynamically?
I have generated one back button component in my Angular 15 project and I want to show this back button across multiple pages in my project. I want to dynamically go back to previous screen using Angular routing so I have defined the back button component like:
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-back-button',
      templateUrl: './back-button.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./back-button.component.css']
    })
    
        export class BackButtonComponent implements OnInit {
        
          constructor(private router: Router) {}
          ngOnInit(): void {
        
          }
        
          goBack(url: string): void {
            this.router.navigate([url]);
          }
        }

     <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="centered-button">
     <mat-icon>reply</mat-icon>
     <span class="button-text">Back</span>
     </button>

     </div>
     <app-back-button (click)="goBack('/')"></app-back-button>
     </div>

This won't work because goBack method should be in component where it is used but I don't want to define goBack() method in every component where back button is used. I want back button component to dynamically handle the routing.

You can use the Location Service from @angular/common.
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-back-button',
  templateUrl: './back-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./back-button.component.css']
})

export class BackButtonComponent implements OnInit {
    
constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) {}
      
ngOnInit(): void {}
    
 goBack(): void {
   this.location.back();
 }
}

